# Separate functions without duplicating code

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently working on a program to traverse through a list of numbers with two different functions to find the sum and a specific value. Here is the code that I have implemented

```
class Program
{
    static int i, sum;
    static List<int> store = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            store.Add(i);
        }

        i = 0;
        TraverseList();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void TraverseList()
    {
        while (i < store.Count)
        {
            FindValue();
            FindSum();
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The sum is {0}", sum);
    }

    static void FindValue()
    {           
        if (store[i] == 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value is 40");
        }                
    }

    static void FindSum()
    {
        sum = sum + store[i];
    }
}
```

I was thinking of separating FindSum and FindValue into two different functions and not calling them in TraverseList. Is there any other way of doing it rather the duplicating the common code of list traversal in those two functions as I have done here

```
class Program
{
    static int i, sum;
    static List<int> store = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            store.Add(i);
        }

        i = 0;
        FindValue();
        i = 0;
        FindSum();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void FindValue()
    {
        while (i < store.Count)
        {
            if (store[i] == 40)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value is 40");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    static void FindSum()
    {
        while (i < store.Count)
        {
            sum = sum + store[i];
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The sum is {0}", sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is extremely bad, the most blatant offense being that your methods `FindValue` and `FindSum` use hidden parameters (`store` and `i`) for no reason. There is absolutely no need to do things this way. Throw this code away and start again.

Comment: @jon I am a beginner and I have been trying to get things working and I don't even know what hidden parameters are. I will surely do a bit of research on that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I haven't used linq before and dont have much about it

Comment: @AjitPeter: I am just trying to say that you have taken the wrong path here. "Hidden parameters" means that your functions need some things to work with, but that's not mirrored by their signatures (they look like they need no arguments at all). Don't ever do that. In this case, both should accept one argument and you should pass `store[i]` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To find the sum of a series of numbers you can use the simple LINQ function:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
int sum = numbers.Sum();
```

I am not sure what you mean by find a value.  If you want to check if one of the numbers in a series is equal to a certain value you can use the LINQ function `Any`:

```
int myValue = 40;
bool hasMyValue = numbers.Any(i => i == myValue);
```

This uses a lambda expression which executes a function and passes each element in the collection to the function.  The function returns true or false to indicate that the element is a match for the `Any` test.

If instead you want to check for *how many* numbers in a sequence match a certain value you can instead use the `Count` function like so:

```
int numberOfMatches = numbers.Count(i => i == myValue);
```

Comment: Don't call lambda expression parameter `i` - I think that's a bad practice. The OP doesn't want `Any` item.

Comment: FindSum() is only an example of the functionality that I am looking to achieve. So the sum() wouldn't help me. My concern is that if I were to add more functions to manipulate the list I would end up duplicating the list traversal for each function similar to FindSum() or FindValue().

Comment: @AjitPeter You would have to be more specific about exactly *what* you are looking to achieve for advice on how to achieve it.  There are a limitless amount of things you could do with a list and a large number of ways to solve each.  It sounds like you're worried about duplicating the iteration code.  This is literally only one line of code if you use a simple `for` or `foreach` loop.  The only way you can condense it further is to use syntactic sugar like the LINQ statements I've shown you.  Chances are you can use it to solve 95% of your problems.

Comment: Please refer to my chat with @chris where I have mentioned what I am trying to achieve and why I am trying to separate the functions which use the common traverse()

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have a real world problem.  You want to have a large number of different kinds of operations you could perform on a list and you want an easy way to pick and choose which operations to execute.  It sounds like a ridiculous scenario where you might have 30 functions and you want to decide "only run these 23 functions".  Stackoverflow isn't really for questions about *what if* you wanted to do something silly.  See the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  Unless you can provide an *actual real world problem* you need solving we aren't much help to you.

Comment: I fail to understand why it is not a real world problem. So you are saying that if I have a set of 30 functions which all need to traverse through the list the only way possible is to duplicating the code in each and every function that uses it. That itself is a problem with the traversal code having to be same across all the 30. I don't think you have understood the actual problem.

Comment: It's not realistic because not all functions are equal.  The order they are called in can matter.  They can modify the data before the next function modifies it further.  You could be filtering a subset of your list and only modifying that subset in further functions.  Some functions return a result that might not be a list, such as summing the elements of a list and *then* doing something with the sum.  So you can't just say "I have a set of 30 functions".  That's not realistic.  Programming is based on problems, not functions.  Functions are a solution to problems, not the problem itself

Comment: I am talking of functions which operates on the list in the exact way as the two shown in example. In my case the traversal through the list is the common part and it doesn't not modify the list in any way. Say I need to add two separate functions in my code to find the total even numbers and odd numbers respectively, I don't think implementing two separate functions with the same list traversal is an ideal solution as I am duplicating it for each and every function that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - I would use `foreach` instead of `while`, regarding the duplicate code (assuming you are not using Linq) - I think it's fine

A taste how Linq can simplify your code:

```
var FindSum = store.Sum();
var FindValue = store.FindAll(x => x == 40);
```

Comment: `FindAll`? use `Find` or `Exist` or `Any(Linq)` methods

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - No. It seems like he wants all items, look at his code, he doesn't stop iterating after finding first item.

Comment: I guess the linq implementation above will help me only this particular case but my concern is of duplicating the same code (list traversal) for any further functions that I add in the future.

Comment: @AjitPeter - YES this specific code will help you now, but if you learn some more about Linq, you can solve much more complicated problems, and then, the so called duplicated code will be in the Linq code and not yours.

Comment: Linq is really helpful with predefined functions like sum() available already

Answer (score 0):

I cannot stress enough how bad it is to have `i` and `sum` as class members. Especially `i`. It will make your code very fragile, and hard to work with. Try to make each method as isolated from the rest of the code as possible.

Try something like this instead:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    List<int> store = new List<int>();

    for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        store.Add( i );

    FindValue( store );
    FindSum( store );

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void FindValue( List<int> list )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
    {
        if( list[i] == 40 )
            Console.WriteLine( "Value is 40" );
    }
}

static void FindSum( List<int> list )
{
    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
        sum += list[i];

    Console.WriteLine( "The sum is {0}", sum );
}
```

It is perfectly fine (and normal) to duplicate the looping, it's just a single line. You could also use a foreach here.

Also, disregard everyone telling you to use LINQ. You're obviously new to programming and you should learn the basics first.

Comment: I agree that the code here is bad even for the standards an example :)  The above example is just an overview of the functionality that I am trying to achieve. The traversal list is not just a single line of code. I have around 50 lines of code and 3 functions which all use the traversal function. I thought there might be a better way of doing it rather copying the same 50 lines of code 3 times for each function.

Comment: In that case, have one loop, and then pass the list + the index to your different methods. I just wanted to stress that even for an example, never ever reuse `i` as you have done, it's bad for you!

Comment: Is any other way of doing it of which I am unaware of since I am a beginner. I was of the notion that code duplication is not good. Some of the comments earlier said the same that it is alright to have duplicate code.

Comment: Yeah they're right - if you find yourself rewriting the same lines of code all over the place, those lines of code should probably be moved into a method. But don't take it all too far. A single line, something as common as a for/foreach loop, is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Don't think the passing the index would work as I have to traverse through the entire list always for all the three methods.

Comment: Yeah that was if you really wanted the loop outside those methods. It would also complicate other things. So I'd say just have a loop in each of your methods.

Comment: I did move the traversal part to a single method. That's what I have in the very first part of the code. But that results in all the three methods in Traverse() function restricting me to call all the 3 functions together. I would have to comment out the other two if I have to call only one function, which is what I am doing at the moment.

Comment: I dont think commenting out other functions to call only one function is a good programming practice :)

Comment: Yeah another reason for having the loop inside each method then!

Comment: So I guess there is no other better way of doing it and I will have to stick to what I am doing now. I wonder what @jon skeet's answer to this would be.

Comment: His answer would probably to buy a book on programming principles :). There are many good lists floating on SO. You can learn yourself how to be a programmer / coder/ developer, that is true. Yet you cannot do so without the proper learning objects such as books (examples, test projects, courses, guides, blogs, and so on).

I don't want to scare you; Welcome to the world of programmers / developers! Just please, start in a proper way. In the end, it is going to save you a lot of time, and you will actually be able to finish larger projects :).